# Group action on direct product in GAP

Tags: group-actions, gap

I want to define the group action of $G$ on $G \times G$ by left multiplication. For example I have `G:=DihedralGroup(6);`. I created `L:=Elements(G);` and `M:=Cartesian(L,L);`. I am not sure how to write function $G \times M \to M$ as $ g\cdot(h,k) \to (gh,gk)$ in GAP which is needed for `OrbitsDomain` function. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In GAP actions always have to be right actions, so you would have to have $(h,k)\cdot g\mapsto(hg,kg)$ so the action is consistent. (Or you could map to $(g^{-1}h,g^{-1}k)$.)

With this, you could define the action function as this:

```
OnPairsRight:=function(pair,g)
  return [pair[1]*g,pair[2]*g];
end;
```

and then use `o:=OrbitsDomain(G,M,OnPairsRight);`